# How to Clone Sitecore Non SXA Site

Tags: sitecore-client, powershell

I need to create a new site by duplicating/cloning existing site.

Requirements:

- All datasource item on pages should point to new site.
- All datasource item fields like droplink, multilist, generallink should be updated to point to new site.

Note that these are non SXA sites.

How do I clone so that new site will have not have any reference with existing site?

Comment: You need to do this one time or it should be context menu command like the one for SXA?

Comment: no context menu but want to keep scripts in place as it is repetitive process as more sites also needs to be cloned.

Answer (score 1):

You can start with the following scripts and then modify it to achieve what you need.

```
# Specify the source and destination paths
$sourcePath = "/sitecore/content/Path/To/SourceItem"
$destinationPath = "/sitecore/content/Path/To/DestinationItem"

# Copy the item and its descendants
Copy-Item -Path $sourcePath -Destination $destinationPath -Recurse
```

After copying all the items from the old path to the new path you can work on updating the fields. You only need to update the fields those are having the old site item ID like DropLink, General Link, etc.

```
# Update fields to point to the new site path
$item.Fields | ForEach-Object {
    if ($_.type -eq "<your field type>") 
    {
       # Get the value of the field that should be the raw value of item id
       $itemValue = $field.Value
    
       # Get the item and it's path
       $oldItem = Get-Item -ID $itemValue
       $itemPath = $oldItem.Paths.FullPath

       # replace the path with new Site and get the ID 
       $newItemPath = $itemPath.Replace("<old site name>", "<new site name>")
       $newItem = Get-Item -Path "master:$newItemPath"

       $item.Editing.BeginEdit()
       $item[$_.Name] = $newItem
       $item.Editing.EndEdit()
    }
}
```

I have written this script to give you an idea of how you can proceed with this and you can further modify this as per your requirement.

Hope this helps.

Comment: is there way to update General link fields also to point internal links to new site

Comment: Check this thread and you will get idea that how you can update the attributes of general link and this will give you some idea. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50978123/how-to-get-general-link-field-properties-in-sitecore-powershell-extensions